# How to get return value of method given to another activity?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

How to get returned value of the method given below to another activity?

```
    // Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
```

Actually this is a method of DatabasHandler class which my using to get all contacts in list view. So I want to call this function in my VewContact.class (populating listview from sqlite database). Its returning value as contactList. How I can call it in my function?
Hope you Understand.. :)

**ADD (ViewContact):**

```
public class ViewContact extends Activity {
 DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db.getAllContacts();
    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.carsListView);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(ViewContact.this, R.layout.item_view, db.getAllContacts());
    }


    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Make sure we have a view to work with (may have been given null)
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
            }

            // Find the car to work with.
            Contact contact = db.getAllContacts().get(position);

            // Make:
            TextView makeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtMake);
            makeText.setText(contact.getID());

            // Year:
            TextView yearText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtYear);
            yearText.setText("" + contact.getName());

            // Condition:
            TextView condionText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtCondition);
            condionText.setText(""+contact.getPhoneNumber());
            return itemView;

        }

    }}
```

***ERROR(LogCat):***

```
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2961)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at com.parth.targetthebudget.ViewContact$MyListAdapter.getView(ViewContact.java:51)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1593)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1251)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:845)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-17 09:03:24.132: E/AndroidRuntime(17094):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**XML (item_view):**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_txtMake"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Make Shown Here"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_txtYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_txtMake"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_txtMake"
        android:text="2000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_txtCondition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_txtYear"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="Condition shown here"
        android:textSize="20dip" /></RelativeLayout>
```

**XML (activity main):**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMake"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="All My Cars"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/carsListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtMake"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtMake" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why dont you create another Class like DatabaseHandle.class and put your getAllContacts() to it. When you want to use this method you create a new instance of DatabaseHandle and call getAllContacts() method.

Comment: But i able to call it as DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this); and then db.getAllContacts(); but how i can get return value in listview?

Comment: You must be doing something like this: `List<Contact> cont = db.getAllContacts();` then you can use it to populate your list view. Can you also show the code where you are creating a ListView and are trying to set the Adapter with this list which would be returned.?

Comment: Edited with error @ShobhitPuri

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace. The line number of error cannot be seen in above Log. Please post the detailed Log. Thanks. Some resource that you've used has a error.

Comment: Please help me out with this. I am with everything still not getting solution :(

Comment: I think you should not use ArrayAdapter like that. You extends your adapter by BaseAdapter.
Could you post full stack trace of your logcat?

Comment: Yes See above I already added that before!

Comment: I update my Comment: Why dont you create a variable mContactList = db.getAllContacts(); and use this in everywhere you need instead of call this function everywhere. 
At last the logcat error is very strange. Could you modify your code as I recommend and try. If has error post your logcat here

Answer (score 0):

List < Contact> allcontacts =db.getAllContacts();

Comment: Any briefing how or why?